# When sequencial search is better than binary search?

Tags: binary-search, linear-search

I know that:

A **linear search** looks down a list, one item at a time, without jumping. In complexity terms this is an O(n) search - the time taken to search the list gets bigger at the same rate as the list does.

A **binary search** is when you start with the middle of a sorted list, and see whether that's greater than or less than the value you're looking for, which determines whether the value is in the first or second half of the list. Jump to the half way through the sublist, and compare again etc.

Is there a case where the **sequencial/linear search** becomes more eficient than **Binary Search** ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, e.g. when the item you are looking for happens to be one of the first to be looked at in a sequential search.